# Parallel Sorting of std::vector in cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting, tbb

**Overview**

I was writing a code for sorting `std::vector<std::string>` in multithreading. 
So i used concept of mergeSort where I divided my vector in chunks and sorted the chunks and then merged it. 
All Sorting and merge was done on the base vector. No assignment was done during the process

I did sorting in parallel and once sorting was complete, I merged the vector in parallel.
That gave me a drastic improvement in runtime as compared to `std::sort` which was single threaded provided my vector size was greater than 10,000

Now when i ran `tbb::parallel_sort` on the same vector having size > 10000, I was able to achieve same runtime. 
But when i was running `__gnu_parallel::sort` it was 2x faster.

**Question**

What does `__gnu_parallel::sort` does extra as compared to previous approach?

Comment: Sorting performance very much depends on data and QUI. There is no generic sorting algorithm that would provide best performance in general and this hold for both sequential and multi-threaded algorithms and their implementations. I usually got the best results with parallel (multi-way) merge sort from GNU parallel mode of libstdc++ (`__gnu_parallel`) with balanced quick sort being only slightly slower (with advantage of being in-place and disadvantage of not being stable). The implementation from TBB (in-placed parallel QS) was always slower in my measurements, it's likely not so fine-tuned.

Comment: yes @DanielLangr. I did multiple experiments and for all _gnu_parallel gave best result.

Comment: Sorry, typo, QUI should be QOI - quality of implementation. Also, I don't think this question is "answerable". The best you can do is to study implemented algorithms and their implementations and compare them. Source code of both libstdc++ and TBB is publicly available. Note that parallel partitioning and parallel multi-way merge are quite complex (recursive parts of both parallel QS and MS are the easier parts).